# A verb for "picking small bits of food from the tray or the main plate before it is served or others have started eating"

Tags: single-word-requests, food

I am looking for a verb that means *to pick small portions of food usually stealthily before it is served for everyone especially from the main plate*. I believe it can be the same verb used when people *insert their finger in a cake to taste some cream before a wish is made or candles are blown*.

Here are some examples of how I would like to use it in a sentence:

1. Kids! Do not [the verb] the food. Go to the dining room and wait at the table.
2. Don't [the verb] the food with your dirty finger. Go wash your hands.
3. He was [the verb] the chicken nuggets before everyone came to the table.

Comment: We usually say ***pick at***. As in *don't pick at the food!*.

Comment: *Behave like a pig*? Or if you want a transitive verb *Don't pig at the food*!

Comment: "Don't pick at your food. It'll never heal."

Comment: `Graze` was the first thing that came to mind for me, but that's already taken, so I'd go with `nibble`

Comment: ***Peck at*** is also used, in addition to ***pick at*** that Dan Bron pointed out.  The analogy is to a bird, eating a tiny little bit at a time.  (Also, in some accents, "pick" is pronounced like "peck.")

Answer (score 18):

The first word that occurs to me is [sample](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+sample):

> - a small part or quantity intended to show what the whole is like.
> - try the qualities of (food or drink) by tasting it.
>
>   - synonyms:  try (out), taste, test, put to the test, experiment with; appraise, evaluate, test drive, check out
>   - "we sampled the culinary offerings"
> - get a representative experience of.

Kids! Do not **sample** the food.

Don't **sample** the food with your dirty finger.

He was **sampling** the chicken nuggets before everyone came to the table.

Comment: Although it doesn’t inherently have the notion of “stealth” (which could explain the early drive-by down-vote), +1 for the first word that came to my mind. Too bad we can’t merge answers and get the OP to accept phrases, because “Don’t [sneak samples](https://books.google.com/books?id=D9MqP9br4sIC&pg=PA12&dq=%22sneak+samples%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUm5TJhdLLAhXIsh4KHb7VD5oQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22sneak%20samples%22&f=false) of the food” would be a good one, imo.

Comment: All the current answers are good, but this is currently my favorite, because OP's question has examples where the food-taking is blatant, and [currently] all the other answers have an element of stealth or sneakiness about them.

Comment: I may probably be wrong but reading the example sentences with "sample" sounds too formal. I like @DanBron's suggestion in comment - "pick at", which I feel would be the more colloquial/leisurely way of saying it.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has so many votes. The very nature of someone (likely a child) taking food before they're allowed, or of someone telling them not to, is informal. As @BiscuitBoy says, "sample" is far too formal. No parent tells their kids to *"stop sampling the food"* The fact that your choice of word technically defines the situation doesn't mean it's an appropriate choice for the context. Additionally, there is nothing stealthy about "sampling".

Comment: @BadHorsie It has upvotes presumably because people agree that it's the answer? I'm not trying to be flippant, but I would definitely tell kids to stop sampling food (well, I'd probably just let them do it, but that's another matter). I'm about as informal as they come, so maybe it's a regional thing? Maybe that's why people seem to agree with me? Also, OP's examples don't really include an element of sneakiness, despite their original description, so there's a bit of a mismatch there. Either way thanks for the input, but I think the formality might be regional or cultural?

Answer (score 16):

My parents (both of whom were US-born with roots in the Midwest) would use **snitch** for exactly this purpose:

> To steal (something, usually something of little value); pilfer: *snitched a cookie from the counter.*  [(Free Dictionary)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snitch)

However, the other usage of the word (to inform or tattle on someone) is probably much more common these days, so using "snitch" in this way may cause confusion in the reader/listener.

Other possible alternatives are **pilfer** and **filch,** though in my mind both of these have more of a sense of criminality than "snitch" does.

Answer (score 12):

I don't believe a specific word exists but what comes to mind is **filch** See the  [Merriam Webster example](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/filch)

> too hungry to wait until the party had started, he filched a cookie from the buffet table when no one was looking

It fits your examples 1) and 3) but I'm less comfortable with 2).  There I believe **grab** or **grab at** would be more appropriate since the emphasis is not on taking sneakily but on the hand contact.

Comment: That’s a good one, imo and here’s [another definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/filch) of it that even uses “takes surreptitiously” [instead of/along with “steals,” which might be a bit too harsh in these contexts] and it uses “in small amounts,” which could arguably be slightly more fitting than 'Merriam’s' “something [that is] small” in these contexts (just the small crumbs of the cookie and not the whole small cookie itself).

Answer (score 11):

Consider. ***sneak***

> To move, give, take, or put in a quiet, stealthy manner: *sneak candy into one's mouth*; *sneaked a look at the grade sheet*.
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sneaking+up+on)
>
> *Billy snuck a cookie from the dessert table* [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/573/04/)

In your examples,

> *Kids! Do not **sneak** samples of the food. Go to the dining room and wait at the table.*
>
> *Don't **sneak** scraps of the food with your dirty fingers. Go wash your hands.*
>
> *He was **sneaking** bits of the chicken nuggets before everyone came to the table.*

Comment: I agree with *sneak* (as in *sneak a bite*), but *sneak up on* doesn't describe the act of taking or picking at food. And usually one does not *sneak up on* a cake, because a cake is inanimate. We typically reserve *sneak up on* for victims who *themselves* can catch us (if a third party can catch us in the act, we usually characterize that as simply *sneaking*).

Comment: Unless the cake is a sentient being, I wouldn't worry too much about sneaking up on it, but sneaking bits of the cake is entirely plausible and commonly understood for the OP's meaning.

Comment: +1 and please see my comment to @Kevin

Comment: The edit made it even weirder. I can't tell from your profile whether you're a native speaker or not, but if you are, would you *actually say* "Kids, don't sneak up on the food"? (And I don't mean in a joking way, or if you all lived on the savannah and subsisted on cagey antelope.) How does one even "sneak up on" food *using* "dirty fingers"? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DanBron Does "sneak up" make any more sense to you, Dan?

Comment: @Elian No, in "sneak up the food" it sounds like you're trying to use "up" as it is used in, e.g. "pull up" or "suck up [in a vacuum]" or "take up", but "sneak up" is a idiom with a fixed meaning. It means to stealthily approach a target, so it can't be used the way you're trying to use it. Your "sneaking bits of chicken" is perfectly apt, but I'd advise against trying to include any other forms, phrasal verbs, or *sneak* + preposition options in your answer. *Sneak* is a good answer, leave it at that.

Answer (score 8):

In my (extended) family we call this "grazing" -- may be idiomatic to us though!

eg. Stop grazing on the turkey!

Comment: Grazing was the first word that came to mind also, but it doesn't really have the connotation of picking at it before others have had a chance in our family. "We're not going to have a sit-down dinner tonight - we'll just graze on the left-overs from the party. Help yourself whenever you're hungry."

Answer (score 3):

One option in BrEng is *snaffle*. From [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snaffle):

> to take something ​quickly for yourself, in a way that ​prevents someone ​else from having or using it

In your examples:

- Kids! Do not **snaffle** the food.
- Don't **snaffle** the food with your dirty finger.
- He was **snaffling** the chicken nuggets before everyone came to the table.

Admittedly, the second option doesn't feel particularly right to me, but generally it works.

---

Other options are [*nick*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nick) or [*pinch*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pinch). Particularly in BrEng.

Both have the same BrEng Informal definition:

> to ​steal something

Again, these feel fine for 1. 2 doesn't really work however, and 3 works, but perhaps feels a little off:

- Kids! Do not **pinch/nick** the food.
- Don't **pinch/nick** the food with your dirty finger.
- He was **pinching/nicking** the chicken nuggets before everyone came to the table.

Comment: Like "nick" and "pinch", "snaffle" is also much more common in British English than American English.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks, I missed that in the definition. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: As an American, I would have had *no* idea what "snaffle" meant without reading this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not a single word -- I'm not convinced there is a single word -- but what occurs to me as the clearest and most precise phrase is *stealing a bite*.

Answer (score 1):

Not food related but perhaps these convey the idea ...

**to nab**

> to take or get (something) quickly and often in a way that is clever or rude. e.g. *We nabbed seats in the front row of the theater.* -- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nab

Or

**to pilfer**

> to steal; especially :  to steal stealthily in small amounts and often again and again -- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilfer

Answer (score 1):

The word ***nosh*** could be used for these situations.

It really means *to eat a snack*, but its etymology derives from the German word ***naschen***, which means *to eat on the sly*. <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nosh)</sub>

> 1. Kids! Do not ***nosh*** the food. ...
> 2. Don't ***nosh*** the food with your dirty finger. ...
> 3. He was ***noshing*** the chicken nuggets before everyone came to the table.

Comment: In British English, there is a slang usage of *nosh* to mean *fellatio*, but the context here is clearly food.

Answer (score 1):

Another term for this is "cherry-pick" (not sure if that counts as a single word or not) - it carries a sense of "taking the best parts out of the collection".

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cherry%E2%80%93pick); [metaphorical usage in git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Comment: Hi rosuav, welcome to EL&U and thanks for your first answer! It's pretty good as first answers go, but usually we ask that people answering questions include links and references to support their assertions: could you please edit in a link to a formal definition of this term? You're more likely to get upvotes from other members if you can back up your answers. - [From Review](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/171524)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, John; I've added a Merriam-Webster link, and also a derivative usage from git, as analogous usage implies that the expression is meaningful enough to build on.

Answer (score -1):

In Italy (Naples at least) we have a work exactly for that: *spizzicare*

And according to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spizzicare) and [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/spizzicare), it translates to *nibble* or *peck at*

Comment: Can you please comment downvotes?

Comment: Not my downvote, but to nibble is to take little bites and to peck at means to take small bits at a time (as though you're not very hungry), but neither is stealthy or involves taking bits from the main serving plate before the meal is served.